# For all $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, $(xy^T)^+=(x^Tx)^+(y^Ty)^+yx^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

I actually spent several days on this one. Really don't know how to prove. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

> Show that for all $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$, $(xy^T)^+=(x^Tx)^+(y^Ty)^+yx^T$.

Comment: what you mean for + sign?

Comment: Well, it means Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

Answer (score 1):

This argument is valid in the case when $x$ and $y$ are both nonzero vectors, which is the nontrivial case (the result can easily be verified if $x=0$ or $y=0$).

If $U \Sigma V^*$ is the SVD of $A$, then [$A^+ = V \Sigma^+ U^*$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Singular_value_decomposition_(SVD)) and since 
$$
xy^\top = \frac{x}{||x||}(||x||\cdot||y||)\frac{y^\top}{||y||},
$$
it follows that 
\begin{align*}
(xy^\top)^+ 
&= \frac{y}{||y||}(||x||\cdot||y||)^+\frac{x^\top}{||x||} \\
&= \frac{y}{||y||^2} \cdot\frac{x^\top}{||x||^2} \\
&= \frac{y}{y^\top y}\cdot \frac{x^\top}{x^\top x} \\
&= (x^\top x)^+ (y^\top y)^+y x^\top, 
\end{align*}
which establishes the result when both vectors are nonzero.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see.